# How to get the next row value only in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

In my table I have two columns (id, score):

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Score |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 3.50  |
| 2  | 3.65  |
| 3  | 4.00  |
| 4  | 3.85  |
| 5  | 4.00  |
| 6  | 3.65  |
+----+-------
```

If you use order `DESC` by clause on `score` then the overall table will be:

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Score |
+----+-------+
| 3  | 4.00  |
| 5  | 4.00  |
| 4  | 3.85  |
| 2  | 3.65  |
| 6  | 3.65  |
| 1  | 3.5   |
+----+-------+
```

My question is how would get the `next score` value when you are iterating over it.

For example, if I am in `row 1` then I want to access the `row 2` `score` value which is 4.00. I have tried using `inner join` but it is not working. I only want to access the next row `score` value. `Inner join limit 1` is giving me upper row values as well. If you see my query below:

```
select 
    c2.score
from
    rank c1
        join
    rank c2 ON c2.id != c1.id
order by c1.score DESC , c2.score DESC
limit 1
```

My end result should like this : I need do rank according to score

```
+-------+------+
| Score | Rank |
+-------+------+
| 4.00  | 1    |
| 4.00  | 1    |
| 3.85  | 2    |
| 3.65  | 3    |
| 3.65  | 3    |
| 3.50  | 4    |
+-------+------+
```

Comment: what would your expected result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what your discussion about getting the next score has to do with calculating the rank.  If you want to calculate the rank without variables, then you can do:

```
select r.*,
       (select count(distinct r2.score)
        from rank r2
        where r2.score >= r.score
       ) as rank
from rank r;
```

In MySQL, this normally more efficient using variables:

```
select r.*,
       (@rn := if(@s = r.score, @rn,
                  if(@s := r.score, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                 )
       ) as rank
from rank r cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @s := -1) params
order by r.score desc;
```

Comment: My query for rank was this : `set @rownum = 0;
select *, (@rownum := @rownum + 1 ) as rank from rank order by score DESC;` so I wanted to add a if condition on `@rownum` that only increment if my score value is different.

Comment: @python . . . That is what both of these queries do.  You can't just get the value from the next row for such a ranking, because there might be more than two similar values in a row.

Comment: That can be handled by next row right value? I am checking for every row.

Comment: Could you add some comments or elaborate your query ? Its giving me the correct result, maybe talk about the technique that you have used.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Could you show me an example in which we can access the next row value ? Any simple example please

Comment: @python . . . That is a different question from ranking the rows.  It should be asked as a separate question.